# Delays within tasks in system verilog

Tags: system-verilog

I am trying to call 4 tasks within another task as follows:

```
task execute();

logic [0:3]     req1, port_select;
logic [0:3]     req2;
logic [0:3]     req3;
logic [0:3]     req4;

logic [0:31]    data11, data21;
logic [0:31]    data12, data22;
logic [0:31]    data13, data23;
logic [0:31]    data14, data24;


bfm.reset_task();

//drive multiple ports 
//repeat(1) 
    //begin: random_stimulus
        port_select = generate_combination();
            repeat(1)
                begin: per_combination_iteration    
                    //port1
                    req1 = port_select[0]? generate_command() : 0;
                    data11 = generate_data();
                    data21 = generate_data();
                    //bfm.drive_ip_port1(req,data1,data2);

                    //port2
                    req2 = port_select[1]? generate_command() : 0;
                    data12 = generate_data();
                    data22 = generate_data();
                    //bfm.drive_ip_port2(req,data1,data2);

                    //port3
                    req3 = port_select[2]? generate_command() : 0;
                    data13 = generate_data();
                    data23 = generate_data();
                    //bfm.drive_ip_port3(req,data1,data2);

                    //port4
                    req4 = port_select[3]? generate_command() : 0;
                    data14 = generate_data();
                    data24 = generate_data();
                    //bfm.drive_ip_port4(req,data1,data2);

                    fork 
                                            bfm.drive_ip_port1(req1,data11,data21);
                                            bfm.drive_ip_port2(req2,data12,data22);
                                            bfm.drive_ip_port3(req3,data13,data23);
                                            bfm.drive_ip_port4(req4,data14,data24);

                    join


                end: per_combination_iteration
    //end: random_stimulus 
$stop; 
endtask: execute
```

And one of my `drive_ip_port` function is as follows:

```
//driving port2

task drive_ip_port2(input logic [0:3] req2, input logic [0:31] data1_port2, data2_port2);
    req2_cmd_in = req2;                             //req2 command
    req2_data_in =  data1_port2;                //req2 first operand
    #200;           
    req2_cmd_in = 0;
    req2_data_in = data2_port2;             //req2 second operand 
    #1000;
endtask: drive_ip_port2
```

This is what I am trying to achieve:
I want the execute task to drive 4 ports randomly. On the first clock, I want them to send a command and data. And then on the next clock, the command should be 0 and only data need to be sent.

This is what I have tried: 
As shown in my code, I have written the above code. The thought behind this code was that since tasks can handle time delays, I can call the task once and pass the data and the command and let task handle all the work.

The problem I have:
After the first clock period, I have a delay of #200(equal to my clock). Thereafter, the wire should become 0 and should remain 0 for #1000. However, I am never getting the value 0 on command. It looks like the command gets driven by this task again. I have tried using Local variables, using the watch feature, using breakpoint but still couldn't debug it. Can anyone suggest what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why `req2_cmd_in` does not get set to zero. Maybe there is somewhere else an overriding assignment like a typo in another task. (Try call only one task and see what that does.)

I do know that if you want something to happen at or after a clock, wait for that clock, do not use a delay. Safest is also to make sure you start at a determined point from a clock edge. Therefore I prefer to use in my test-benches code like this:

```
task drive_ip_port2(input logic [0:3] req2, 
                    input logic [0:31] data1_port2, data2_port2);
    // Use this or make sure you call the task at a 
    // determined point from the clock
    @ (posedge clk) ; 

    // Signals here change as if they come from a clocked register
    req2_cmd_in  <= req2;                    //req2 command
    req2_data_in <=  data1_port2;            //req2 first operand

    @ (posedge clk) ; 
    req2_cmd_in  <= 0;                       // No command
    req2_data_in <= data2_port2;             // only req2 second operand 

    repeat (4)  // 4 or 5 depends on if you wait for clock at top
       @ (posedge clk) ; 
endtask: drive_ip_port2
```

Comment: I would go one step further and use the negedge of the clock for stimulus if the DUT uses the posedge.

Comment: @dave_59 Agreed, that is also a solution I have used. Any idea about the  `req2_cmd_in = 0;` not seemed to be executed?